# Converting a VB.NET Shared Function to C#

Tags: c#

I used a converter program to convert this vb to C#

```vb
Public Overloads Shared Function ExecuteReader(ByVal statement As String, ByVal commandType As CommandType, _
    ByVal paramCollection As ArrayList, ByVal connectionDelegate As OpenDatabaseConnection, _
    ByVal outputConnectionObject As IDbConnection, ByVal CommandTimeout As Int16) As InstantASP.Common.Data.IDataReader

Return PrivateExecuteReader(Configuration.AppSettings.DataProvider, _
    statement, commandType, paramCollection, connectionDelegate, outputConnectionObject, CommandTimeout)

End Function
```

I'm not familiar with VB.NET and I don't know why this converter converted it to C# with all these refs.  I don't even use ref much if at all and don't think this is the best/cleanest way to convert this.  But I'm having trouble understanding all this including the conversion and if this makes any sense whatsoever after the conversion.

```cs
public static IDataReader ExecuteReader(string statement, CommandType commandType, ArrayList paramCollection, OpenDatabaseConnection connectionDelegate, IDbConnection outputConnectionObject, Int16 commandTimeout)
{
    return PrivateExecuteReader(ref AppSettings.DataProvider(), ref statement,
        ref commandType, ref paramCollection, ref connectionDelegate,
        ref outputConnectionObject, ref commandTimeout);
}
```

Comment: What does the parameter list look like for `PrivateExecuteReader(...)`?

Comment: Not sure yet.  I'm converting a software code package I'm going to be buying and have not run this yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It put the `ref` on those parameters because `PrivateExecuteReader()` declares them as `ref` (C#) or `ByRef` (VB.NET). There isn't a choice.

In VB.NET, you just pass in your arguments and have to look at the method's declaration (or Intellisense hints) to know whether it's by reference or by value. But in C#, if a method declares a parameter as `ref`, then you also have to mark the argument you're passing as `ref` so that it is explicit that you understand that it is being passed by reference.

Looks like a [mostly] correct conversion to me.

Comment: thanks.  I'm getting a 'ref' argument is not classified as a variable error on the ref AppSettings.DataProvider().  I guess you can't pass in a method, just a variable correct?

Comment: the implementation of DataProvider starts like this:   public static Providers DataProvider()
  {
   // get provider from web.config
   string strDataProvider = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("InstantASP_DataProvider"));

Comment: If the first parameter for `PrivateExecuteReader()` is whatever `Appsettings.DataProvider()` returns, you may have to stick it in a variable and then pass the variable. Can't tell without knowing more about the declaration of `Configuration.AppSettings.DataProvider` (method vs property, return type), and the first parameter type of `PrivateExecuteReader()`.

Comment: And you're not really passing in a method, you're passing in what the method is returning. But `ref` needs a storage reference (variable, field, property, etc.) and the return from the method doesn't satisfy that.

Comment: cool thanks.  I shoved that Provider value into a private field and used that throughout the class.  Cleaner anyway this way and should have been done this way in the first place by the VB.NET dev